# How to trigger a function when a Session Window expires due to inactivity

Tags: apache-flink

I am using Session Window to keep track of session events and want to clean up resources when the session window expires.

How do I get notification without having to write external timers etc. when window will expire because of inactivity.

e.g. The life of session window will extend by 10 minutes every time an event is received in the example below. After 10 mins of inactivity the window will expire so want to execute some code on this expiration.

```
input
    .keyBy(<key selector>)
    .window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.minutes(10)))
    .trigger(CountTrigger.of(1))
    .<windowed transformation>(<window function>);
```

Comment: Isn't that just how the session window works ?:) After there is no data for given key for 10 minutes it will automatically close the window and pass it ot Your windowed transformation.

Comment: I have a trigger that executes on every event added to the stream. Since the trigger is already executed for last element, there is no windowing trigger that executes after last 10 mins of inactivity. Updated the code to reflect the trigger.

Comment: You should be able to implement custom Trigger that can do both :)

Comment: Took your advice and attempted it. So far my response is mixed. Could you post a sample with event time. My understanding improved with all the readings, but so has my confusion. I was never able to get OnEvent to fire on timeout. Since this timeout is based on processing time so I can understand that onEventTime  might not fire. Tried to use periodic watermark generator, custom triggers and autointerval but to no avail. Finally only thing that worked was jump out into processing timer and Issue a final purge.

Comment: Adding few refs: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62059837/how-to-implement-a-flink-event-time-trigger-that-emits-after-no-events-recieved
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63644801/flink-time-characteristic-and-autowatermarkinterval
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61020086/flink-window-function-getresult-not-fired  This is probable a dupe of first link.